# Canceling Notifications Laravel 5.3 (Via)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

So, let's say that I want to have my Notification Check logic within Via (as in, should this be sent based on a variable on the User).  I notice that, if I do it this way in via:

```
return $notifiable->comment_email ? ['mail'] : false;
```

it will successfully send if comment_email is true on the User.  However, if it is false, then I want the notification to be cancelled all together, which I assumed returning False would do - it does not, just throws an error.  So how would I cancel it in the via? Is it possible?

Comment: Curiously, what is the error it throws? Does it expect an array? maybe `[false]` or `[]` would do?

Comment: If I switch it to [false], it reports 'driver not supported'. But [] does work!  You can create the answer if you would like, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead return false you must return an empty array:

```
return $notifiable->comment_email ? ['mail'] : [];
```

Comment: In fact of phpunit, this seems to be no cancle. "assertNotSentTo" fails with an empty via array return